# In-line revision diff when a message is edited in Chat

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits, chat

I noticed that when someone edits one of their messages, it appears in red for everyone else.

Can we instead see a **revision diff inline**, indicating what was added, deleted, and modified?

Answer (score 3):

This is really overkill for a chat.

Answer (score 1):

For info, there **is** a full edit history, available in the message popup. This only appears once something has been edited. You also get an on-screen edit glyph, to help make it obvious.